# Changing color and underlining text output of excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I would like the output of a simple `IF' statement in excel to be changed to red and underlined.  I can't figure out for the life of me how to do it.  Heres a simple version of what I would like:

```
    +---+--------------------------------+
    | A |               B                |
+---+---+--------------------------------+
| 1 | 1 | =IF(A1>0,"do nothing","print") |
| 2 |   |                                |
| 3 |   |                                |
| 4 |   |                                |
| 5 |   |                                |
+---+---+--------------------------------+
```

Where `print` would be returned underlined and in red font.
thanks so much,  Josh

Comment: Could use conditional formatting? Or VBA?? Oe just formulas???

Comment: any help would be appreciated where conditional formatting or formulas. I don't know much on VBA

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Conditional Formatting for this. You can format a cell based on a formula. It's in the Styles section of the Home ribbon.

1. Select Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
2. Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
3. Put your formula in there
4. Click "Format..." and set the text and cell formatting to whatever you'd like

You could also use the "Format only cells that contain" option in conditional formatting. Choose Format only cells with: Specific Text, and set that to format any cells containing the word "Print".

Comment: Thank you but I receive the error,"You cannot use relative references in Conditional Formatting criteria for color scales, data bars, and icon sets.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you used this answer please hit the green check next to it to notify other users that this worked for you and it will help me increase my reputation :) Thanks.